# Jstree Container is empty

Tags: javascript, jstree

My Div

```
<div id="container">
```

The Jstree Configuration

```
$('#container').jstree({
'core' : {
    'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
  'data' : {
    "url" :apex.server.url ({p_request: "APPLICATION_PROCESS=GET_NODE_DATAA",x01: 0 || 0,x02: "LOADA" }),
      "dataType" : "json", // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
    "dataFilter" : function (new_data) {
      return new_data ;
    }
  }
}
```

});

Data Comming for the Server after run the jstree configuration and the new_data output

```
[{"data":{"title":"Form Modules(15)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"form"},"attr":{"id":"1149043"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"PL/SQL Libraries(16)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"pll"},"attr":{"id":"1149044"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"Menu Modules(2)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"menu"},"attr":{"id":"1149045"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"Object Libraries(5)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"olb"},"attr":{"id":"1149046"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"Report Modules(12)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"onrptprop"},"attr":{"id":"1149047"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"APEX Applications(5)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"apex"},"attr":{"id":"1149048"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"Database Objects(1701)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"database"},"attr":{"id":"1149049"},"state":"closed"},{"data":{"title":"ASCII FILES(11)","attr":{"href":"#"},"icon":"ascii"},"attr":{"id":"1149061"},"state":"closed"}]
```

But the jstree show like in the screeshot

[screeshot. But it dont display Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxYd8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer isn't a conventionnal way to use Json, but if you can return an html string server-side, you can use jsTree with HTML feed methode : it works with `<ul>` and `<li>` where `<ul>` il a node. I'm sure that you need your IDs to do something afterward, but then try to use `data` arttributein your HTML string to get it

Comment: Hey , have a Look at the Screeshot above.  have change the Format and it display only the Icons but no the Data.

Comment: example : <li id='list_1' data-id='12548'>jsTree</li> will show you a folder named jsTree. In the HTML code, there will be an attribute called : data-id that you can access with : (in JQuery) $('#list_1').data('id')